# Visual basic 2010 Check if file exists on form load

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

I would like my Visual Basic app to run a splash screen with a progress bar and after that to check if file exists, but I have a problem since as soon as I start and the splash screen shows up the file checker fires up, but I would like it to check when `form1` loads and not splash screen. Here is my code, I could use an advice:

**Splash screen :**

```
Public NotInheritable Class SplashScreen1

    'TODO: This form can easily be set as the splash screen for the application by going to the "Application" tab
    '  of the Project Designer ("Properties" under the "Project" menu).       

    Private Sub Splashscreen1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Dte As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Label2.Text = FormatDateTime(Dte, DateFormat.LongDate)

        Timer1.Start()
        Timer2.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form 1 :**

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "/read me.txt") Then
            MsgBox("file found")
        Else
            MsgBox("not found")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Only use a splash screen when you *need* one, 50 milliseconds isn't enough.  Similarly, only use a progress bar when you *know* how long it will take.  You don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your Form1 code from the Load event to the Shown event. Load is run before the form is visible to the user, which is not what you want from what I understand.

Comment: That did the trick ,i just changed Handles Me.load to Handles Me.Shown. 

thanks Jason !

Answer (score 0):

Your timer1_tick event is causing this issue.  Timer1 is enabled at splashscreen load and depending on the timer_interval it may never display before form1 loads.  Do you want the user to see something during this time?

The progress bar implies an action or set of actions is taking place.  What do you have taking place that requires the progress bar?  If you want the illusion of things happening, make sure you timer1 interval is greater than your timer2 interval since timer1 controls how long the splashscreen is visible  before form1 is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
      Form1.Show()
      Me.Close()
End If
```

change to:

```
If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
      Form1.Visible = True
      Me.Visible = False
End If
```